# Pug js how span element left inside a tag

Tags: pug, jade4j

i wonder how i can span element put to left inside of a tag?

my syntax now:

```
 a Settings
        span 
          img(src=setting)
```

it's rendering like:

```
<a>Settings <span><img src="settings.png"/></span>
```

i tried to make:

```
 a
   span 
     img(src=setting) Settings
```

i want to make:

```
<a><span><img src="settings.png"/> Settings</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Piped Text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#piped-text) syntax:

**Pug:**

```
a
  span
    img(src=setting)
    | Settings
```

**HTML:**

```
<a><span><img src="settings.png"/>Settings</span></a>
```